# JavaScript Array weird initialization

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, google-chrome, firefox

I've stumbled upon something strange....
Maybe someone can try explaining the difference between these two:

```
var a1=Array(2);
var a2=Array.apply(null,a1);
console.log(a1);
console.log(a2);
console.log(a1[0]===a2[0]);
```

notice the items are equal but the console log of the arrays looks different (on Chrome and NodeJS).

also other aspects of them seem to work differently:

```
a1.map(function(i){console.log("!");})
a2.map(function(i){console.log("!");})
```

notice that map itereares only for a2 not for a1.

this happens on NodeJS, Chrome and FF.

Comment: Without checking the documentation, I'd say that `a1=Array(2)` sets `a1` to an array with length 2, but doesn't explictly assign any elements. Whereas `a2=Array.apply(null,a1)` is like saying `a2=Array(undefined,undefined)`, i.e., it explicitly sets the value of two elements to `undefined`. `.map()` only iterates elements that have been explicitly set.

Comment: In other words, (I'm guessing that in this case) the key is that `someArray[someIndex]` will return `undefined` for two possible reasons: 1. because the element at `someIndex` was never assigned a value, or 2. because the element at `someIndex` was explicitly assigned `undefined`. And your `a1[0]===a2[0]` test is comparing reason 1 `undefined` with reason 2 `undefined`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, this creates a sparse array:

```
var a = new Array(3) // a = [ , , ,]
```

if you try to iterate over a using `map` or `forEach`, JavaScript skips the holes. The invocation

```
var b = Array.apply(null, Array(3)) // b = [undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

(this is equivalent to invoking the array constructor with `Array(undefined, undefined, undefined)`)

creates a dense array `b`. `b` is almost the same as `a` but now, you can iterate over the elements, in other words, since the array is now dense, map and foreach don't skip over elements.

Comment: 10x for the pointer.... looked into it further and found you can actually distinguish the two cases with: console.log(0 in a1,0 in a2);